# Selenium Inspect : 2 divs same footer

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

I am using Selenium IDE to conduct testing my website.

[image]

Please refer to the above image. I have 2 windows one over the other and I need to get the xpath of the 2nd footer that is the last in the image.

When I use Selenium it picks but does not work as expected. In a situation like this how do I know the xpath and which to use in Selenium.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can  do this to access the 2nd element with that xpath

```
driver.find_element(BY.XPATH,"(//div[@class='footer'])[2]")
```

If you need any of those individual values.

I would use link_text since they all have different text values and are all of a tags.

```
driver.find_element(BY.LINK_TEXT,"Upload")
```